# Django/Python How do I get my receiver to add a value to a field relative to a previous addition - instead of indiscriminately adding to the value?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

Python3.6.4; Django 2.0.  Long time first time, please be gentle

I'm creating a tracking application that accepts multiple work logs to a work order.  I'm trying to track time spent on a workorder by obtaining a time delta from each log and sending it to the work order model to hold the aggregate time.

The problem is, each time I'm updating an existing log it adds the entire time to the work order instead of just the difference.  So if a log was previously 12-2:00 (feeds 2 hours to WorkOrder), and you changed it to 12-1:30 it was feed an additional 1.5 hours to WorkOrder, instead of subtracting 30min

Is there a way I can check to see a time was previously sent to WorkOrder?  I tried updating update_labor_hours to check if the timedelta was < or > the original time, but I couldn't really figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

```
from django.utils.timezone import now
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.


class WorkOrder(models.Model):
    labor_hours = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)


class WorkLog(models.Model):
    work_order = models.ForeignKey(WorkOrder, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    start_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def _time_spent(self):
        return datetime.combine(date.today(), self.end_time) - datetime.combine(date.today(), self.start_time)

    time_spent = property(_time_spent)


def update_labor_hours(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    instance.work_order.labor_hours = instance.work_order.labor_hours + instance.time_spent

    instance.work_order.save()


post_save.connect(update_labor_hours, sender=WorkLog)
```

Comment: I wouldn't do this at all. I would calculate labor_hours on display, by summing time_spent of all the related WorkdLogs.

Comment: Not exactly related to what you asked, but there's this interesting project on github ([django-timepiece](https://github.com/caktus/django-timepiece)) for tracking people's time on projects, maybe you can get some insights on [how they handle the timelog/worklog](https://github.com/caktus/django-timepiece/blob/develop/timepiece/entries/models.py#L158).

Comment: Thanks Daniel - thats exactly what I'm going to do.  Vitor - Thanks!